how to ID a sequence of objects?

I'm designing a block-based tangible programming language which has syntax that reflects text-based code, in that blocks are connected and read in a left-to-right and top-to-bottom manner. There are many block types, which connect in modular sequences to create programs that control a separate interface. As a result, each tangible program is a specific ordered sequence of block types (see left side of attached image).
I'm trying to balance cost, efficiency, and size. Let's estimate that there are about 60 blocks in the kit, and each program ranges between 20-35 blocks. Another constraint is that it's important for the block edges to line up precisely, with no gaps between them, and no fiducial markers.
My thought for making this work is that each block should have an ID, and the "brain block" (a powerful microcontroller) will extract the sequence of block IDs and then construct the corresponding program algorithmically. I'm not sure of the best way to ID the blocks. I have thought of two options, depicted in the attached image. One idea is a "smart block" design, where each block has a tiny microcontroller and communicates through pogo pins and traces that snake within the blocks. The other idea is an RFID board design, where each block has an RFID tag embedded in it and communicates through a board with a grid of RFID readers.
Does anyone have advice? I'm open to guidance on implementations of one of these ideas or completely new ideas.

Can you put a QR code on top of each block, and the 'compile program' action is to photograph them with a phone app? That also puts a 'powerful microcontroller' right in your hand!

That's what I'm trying to avoid. Tangible programming languages are typically designed with fiducial markers, and I find it somewhat of a limitation, especially for what I'm exploring in my project. Because QR codes require a camera, the environment has to be well-controlled in terms of lighting, and physical interactions can occlude the computer vision. Physical interaction thus becomes less intuitive. My system also places a lot of emphasis on the visual design of the blocks, and fiducial markers don't fit into that design.

what else do you want to rule out beforehand? Is the surface an ordinary table top, or can it be a prepared one like a chessboard, with thickness, and stuff buried inside? You only show connections on your north and south sides, are east/west connections not required, perhaps because you have an extended reader stem to the west where your blocks line up?

Something with daisy-chained shift registers perhaps? Have a signal that causes everything in the chain to load its ID from some fixed memory (which can just be pin-strapped parallel load inputs) and then shift everything through the chain bit by bit until you encounter the "end of program" block.

See the comments of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/719120/easiest-way-to-detect-objects-using-diy-materials
